# Django ORM is looking for a column that I dont create never

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Im trying to pull data from external databse with django. I used inspectdb command for get the models, that database have two tables, when I try to get data from the first table, it works...but when I try to get the data from second table throws the next error:

```
1054, "Unknown column 'hotel_reviews.id' in 'field list'"
```

The column id dont exist and its correct, but why its looking for it?

This is how i have the models:

```
from django.db import models


class HotelInfo(models.Model):
    country_area = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    hotel_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    hotel_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hotel_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hotel_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    review_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    review_qty = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    clean = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    comf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    loct = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    fclt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    staff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    vfm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    wifi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'hotel_info'
        unique_together = (('hotel_id', 'country_area'),)
        verbose_name_plural = "hotels"


class HotelReviews(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(db_column='UUID', max_length=36, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hotel_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    review_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    review_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    review_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    review_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    reviewer_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hash_reviewer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewer_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    posting_conts = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    positive_content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    negative_content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n3 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n4 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n4 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n5 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    staydate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'hotel_reviews'
        verbose_name_plural = "Reviews"
```

Then I create the serializer like that:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import HotelInfo
from .models import HotelReviews


class HotelInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelInfo
        fields = '__all__'


class HotelReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelReviews
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is how I have the views:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import HotelInfo
from .models import HotelReviews
from .serializer import HotelInfoSerializer
from .serializer import HotelReviewSerializer


class HotelInfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = HotelInfo.objects.filter(review_qty__gte=5)
    serializer_class = HotelInfoSerializer


class HotelReviewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = HotelReviews.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HotelReviewSerializer
```

And this is the urls:

```
rom rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import HotelInfo
from .models import HotelReviews
from .serializer import HotelInfoSerializer
from .serializer import HotelReviewSerializer


class HotelInfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = HotelInfo.objects.filter(review_qty__gte=5)
    serializer_class = HotelInfoSerializer


class HotelReviewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = HotelReviews.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HotelReviewSerializer
```

Like I said the first table (hotel_info) works, but the second one (hotel_review) throws the error when I try to get data. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `id` is created implicitly if you did not specify a primary key column.

Comment: So since your `HotelReviews` model does not contain a field with `primary_key` is `True`, Django assumes that you implicitly created a field named `id`.

Comment: is there a way to dont create that without use primary key?

Comment: but you have a `uuid` field, so that can be used as primary key. Exactly why would you not make the `uuid` the primary key. It will not change anything at the database side.

Comment: is there by the way a reason why the `uuid` is `null=True`? NULL-able fields are often quite seldom, especially since they make the logic in the views, etc. more complicated since now the item can be a string, or a `None`type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify a field with `primary_key=True`, Django will create one implicitly. This field is named `id` and is an `AutoField`. Since your `HotelReviews` model thus does not specifies a primary key field, it will do that for that model.

You should thus assign the `uuid` as the primary key here:

```
class HotelReviews(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        db_column='UUID',
        max_length=36,
        blank=True
    )
    # …

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'hotel_reviews'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reviews'
```

---

> **Note**: Django has a [**`UUIDField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)
> to specify *universally unique identifiers*. This field also has validators to check if the uuid has the correct
> format and is therefore usually better.